# Jquery mobile - page dynamic content

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a page where the content is loaded through AJAX, no when i visit the page the first time the content loaded through ajax is styled correctly but on subsequent visits to this page the styles are lost.

I have tried calling .page() on the dom to fix the styling but still no success

```
$.get(url,function( data ){
    $("#menu-content").html("");
    $("#menu-content").html(data);
    $.mobile.changePage("#menu_page", {transition: "none"});
    $("#menu_page").page();
    hideLoading();
});
```

Any suggestions

Comment: try removing this $("#menu_page").page(); and maybe this as well hideLoading(); and the $.mobile.changePage() should refresh jQM. Are there any errors in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to swap the statements:

```
$.get(url,function( data ){
    $("#menu-content").html("");
    $("#menu-content").html(data);
    $("#menu_page").page();
    $.mobile.changePage("#menu_page", {transition: "none"});
    hideLoading();
});
```

page should be rendered by jqm first.